# Spring TaskScheduler does not schedule task immediatelly

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I want to execute the same task couple of times but it seems that every next invocation of my code does not execute the task immediately, for example it executes after one minute.

Since user has to schedule tasks manually I use `ScheduledTaskRegistrar.TaskScheduler`.

```
taskRegistrar.getScheduler().schedule(myTask, new Date());
```

What could be the reason? User clicked schedule button twice on my fronted application and backend invoked the above schedule method twice as expected. First execution of my task was immediate, second run after two minutes.

UPDATE: taskregistrar config, maybe I didn't configure it at all. my tasks are added as cron tasks on application deployment. But they also must be runnable manually if user wants to trigger it. Below is more or less the whole logic:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@Component
@Slf4j
@Generated
@Getter
public class ScheduleTaskService implements SchedulingConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    private List< MyTask> taskList;

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        this.taskRegistrar = taskRegistrar;
        taskList.stream().filter(MyTask::isOn).forEach(this::addTaskToScheduler);
    }

    public void addTaskToScheduler(GwoTask task) {
        taskRegistrar.addCronTask(task, task.getCronExpression());
    }
    public void scheduleImmediateInvocation(MyTask myTask) {
        taskRegistrar.getScheduler().schedule(myTask, new Date());
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you configure `ScheduledTaskRegistrar` bean?

Comment: I updated the code snippet. Should I add some configuration?

Comment: yes, please show how you create `ScheduledTaskRegistrar`

Comment: I just dont create it.. I override configureTasks and the default taskRegistrar is coming ..

Comment: I think it because the `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()` is use by default, and second task blocks until first task complete. You may verify by setting larger pool size in `configureTasks`, `        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5));`

Comment: Thank u, I read a bit, search a bit in that direction and you was right, configurint corePoolSize, maxPoolSize, queueCapacity helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By referring to the [source code of ScheduledTaskRegistrar](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v6.0.4/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/scheduling/config/ScheduledTaskRegistrar.java#L380),

```java
    protected void scheduleTasks() {
        if (this.taskScheduler == null) {
            this.localExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            this.taskScheduler = new ConcurrentTaskScheduler(this.localExecutor);
        }
        ...
```

If we do not set `taskScheduler`, `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()` is used by default. Hence new task will be blocked by processing task.

For your use case in `scheduleImmediateInvocation`, I recommend to use another thread pool(Probably from [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)) instead as:

- It isn't actually a schedule job.
- More control on pool size is needed to suit your workload

If you just want to make `ScheduledTaskRegistrar` execute more concurrently, configure it as:

```java
    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        // set the desired core pool size
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5));
        this.taskRegistrar = taskRegistrar;
        // ...
    }
```